# Metadata API knowledgesettings bug (v40.0 with v37.0) - Solved

Tags: metadata-api, soap, knowledge, wsdl

I am using Metadata API version 37 while one of our sandboxes were upgraded to v40 (Spring '17). We ran into an issue while running the statement:

```
ReadResult readResult = mdConnection.readMetadata("KnowledgeSettings",
                    new String[] { "*" });
```

This returned KnowledgeSettings response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <soapenv:Body>
        <readMetadataResponse>
          <result>
            <records xsi:type="KnowledgeSettings">
              <fullName>*</fullName>
              <answers>
                <enableArticleCreation>false</enableArticleCreation>
            </answers>
            <cases>
                <defaultContributionArticleType>How_To</defaultContributionArticleType>
                <editor>standard</editor>
                <enableArticleCreation>true</enableArticleCreation>
                <enableArticlePublicSharingSites>false</enableArticlePublicSharingSites>
                <enableCaseDataCategoryMapping>true</enableCaseDataCategoryMapping>
                <useProfileForPDFCreation>false</useProfileForPDFCreation>
            </cases>
            ---
      </readMetadataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The property enableCaseDataCategoryMapping is not available on v37 but Salesforce sends the response treating it as v40. Can this be avoided by having backward compatibility with the responses?

The issue is that this application is deployed on various environments and getting updates for every new version is quite difficult to maintain.

EDIT: The request is the following:

```
WSC: Creating a new connection to https://instance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/37.0/user Proxy = DIRECT username null
------------ Request start   ----------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope
   xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <env:Header>
  <SessionHeader xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <sessionId>sessionId</sessionId>
  </SessionHeader>
 </env:Header>
 <env:Body>
  <m:readMetadata xmlns:m="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:sobj="null">
   <m:type>KnowledgeSettings</m:type>
   <m:fullNames>*</m:fullNames>
  </m:readMetadata>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

EDIT:

Salesforce support acknowledged this issue and R&D commmented from the ticket that a patch will be supplied on 05/28 for this issue.

Comment: What login URL are you using? If you log in as 37.0, you should get a response as 37.0. If you don't, that's a bug, and probably needs to be reported to salesforce.com.

Comment: Edited with the request. It is hitting the URL v37.0. I'll report it to Salesforce.com

Comment: It certainly has all the hallmarks of a bug. Support case would be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and Salesforce support will be creating a patch for Winter 17.